# QComboBox::findData fails when QVariant stores a std::vector

Tags: qt, stdvector, qvariant

Consider this code:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > v;
v.push_back( std::vector<int>( 1, 4 ) );
v.push_back( std::vector<int>( 1, 3 ) );
QComboBox box;
box.addItem( "", QVariant::fromValue<std::vector<int>>( v[0] ) );
box.addItem( "", QVariant::fromValue<std::vector<int>>( v[1] ) );
int pos = box.findData( QVariant::fromValue<std::vector<int>>(v[0]) );
```

`pos` is `-1`, when `0` was expected.

Manual search (for `i` to `box.count()`) is doable and works. As `( box.itemData( 0 ).value< std::vector<int> >() == v[0] )` surprisingly returns `true`! But `findData` is supposed to work too!

Note: Adding `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE( std::vector<int> );` did not help

Edit 2016/05/03: Filled a Qt bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53152

Comment: Have you tried using a type other than `A`, such as `int`? This will isolate if the problem is with `A` or `std::vector`.

Comment: @JonHarper: Good point. Same problem with `int*`, so apparently the problem comes from `std::vector`

Comment: Perhaps try `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::vector<A *>)`?

Comment: @JonHarper: See last Note in my post, already tried that. Had no effect.

Comment: My answer was completely wrong. `std::vector` is declared by default with [`Q_DECLARE_SEQUENTIAL_CONTAINER_METATYPE`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_SEQUENTIAL_CONTAINER_METATYPE)

Comment: Did not test, it even fails with `std::vector<int>`

Comment: @JonHarper: Fixed thanks to Qt help (see posted answer)

Comment: Good info. Thank you for posting an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[QMetaType::registerComparators](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#operator-eq-eq) has to be called to have `operator==` be used instead of bitwise comparison.

Calling (once): `QMetaType::registerComparators<std::vector<int>>();` makes `findData` work.